# How do you obtain the largest n elements of a list using Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm stuck on a homework question and could use any hints or suggestions. I need to find the *n* largest numbers in a list using Scheme. I am trying to do this by creating helper functions that are called by the main function. So far I have this:

```
(define (get_max_value L)
    (if (null? L)
        '()
      (apply max L)
)

(define (biggest_nums L n)
    (if (null? n)
        '()
      (cons (get_max_value L) (biggest_nums L (- n 1)))
    )
)
```

When I type *(biggest_num '(3 1 4 2 5) 3)* at the command prompt drRacket just hangs and doesn't even return an error message. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It looks like `n` is supposed to be a number. A number will never be an empty list (`null?`).

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the list and then return the first `n` elements.

However, if the list is very long and `n` is not very large, then you probably don't want to sort the whole list first. In that case, I would suggest something like this:

```
(define insert-sorted
  (lambda (item lst)
    (cond ((null? lst)
           (list item))
          ((<= item (car lst))
           (cons item lst))
          (else
           (cons (car lst) (insert-sorted item (cdr lst)))))))

(define largest-n
  (lambda (count lst)
    (if (<= (length lst) count)
        lst
        (let loop ((todo (cdr lst))
                   (result (list (car lst))))
          (if (null? todo)
              result
              (let* ((item (car todo))
                     (new-result
                      (if (< (car result) item)
                          (let ((new-result (insert-sorted item result)))
                            (if (< count (length new-result))
                                (cdr new-result)
                                new-result))
                          result)))
                (loop (cdr todo)
                      new-result)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mains problems with your code:

1. `L` always stays the same. L doesn't decrease in size when you make the recursive call, so the max will always be the same number in every recursive call.
2. You don't ever check `n` to make sure it contains the correct amount of numbers before returning the answer.

To solve these two problems in the most trivial way possible, you can put a `(< n 1)` condition in the `if`, and use something like `(cdr L)` to make `L` decrease in size in each recursive call by removing an element each time.

```
    (define (biggest-nums n L)
      (if (or (empty? L)
              (< n 1))
          '()
          (cons (apply max L) (biggest-nums (- n 1) (cdr L)))))
```

So when we run it:

```
> (biggest-nums 3 '(1 59 2 10 33 4 5))
```

What *should* the output be?

```
'(59 33 10)
```

What is the *actual* output?

```
'(59 59 33)
```

OK, so we got your code running, but there are still some issues with it. Do you know *why* that's happening? Can you step through the code to figure out what you could do to fix it?

Comment: @AlexKnauth, some people rejected your edit, but I found it to be quite nice. I manually merged it into my answer. Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to first sort the numbers in ascending order and then take the `n` first. This translates quite literally in Racket code:

```
(define (biggest_nums L n)
  (take (sort L >) n))
```

It works as expected:

```
(biggest_nums '(3 1 4 2 5) 3)
=> '(5 4 3)
```

Comment: I'm using DrRacket with language R5RS. Typing (sort '(3 9 7 2 4)) gives me an error "sort: undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier". Does DrRacket have a built-in sort function?

Comment: @MNRC of course! you just have to switch language, use `#lang racket`